# How to deploy an Air app from Flash Builder to an non-jailbroken iPad without having a Apple Developer ID?

Tags: ios, ipad, deployment

The tittle says pretty much everything, I just bought an iPad 2 that comes with the 6.1.3 iOS and I've just read that there is no jailbreak method right now.. so, is there a way to deploy apps made in Air just for tests purposes only into the device?, or do I need a developer id to do so?.

(I'm not planning to sell the app in the app store, I just want to test it for practicing purposes only)

Comment: Not possible without jailbreak.

Comment: Oh.. I thought it was only needed when you wanted to publish your app to the appstore.. well.

Comment: You need the developer certificate to test your app on the device.

Comment: And, let say another developer gives me this developer certificate (this developer has a IDP), can I then compile and deploy the app on the device?.

Comment: He'll have to add your device to his allowed hardware, but it should work fine.